# How could I wind up with music in Music.app on my iPhone that I've never heard of?

Tags: iphone, music

I'm getting ready to move to a newer phone, but with less space, so I'm trying to clean off apps that I don't use and music that I don't listen to.  For some mysterious reason there is a TON of music that I don't think I've ever heard of.

Why would music get added to my phone without me intentionally downloading it?  Also, is there any good way to remove lots of things at once?  (It is extremely tedious to do this on the iPhone, where every single item requires one or more individual gestures, which often fail.)

Answer (score 1):

I am going to limit the scope of this answer and question only the question in title.

Music might be downloaded into your iPhone due to automation. For example with Spotify I have subscribed to this one playlist that keeps changing. I have also set it to download the whole playlist everytime there are new songs added.

In your case it really depends on which kind of (music) applications you have downloaded on your phone.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have mentioned that I'm using the default Music app.